# Delete rows by dplyr but leave rownames indexes

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's consider data following :

```
df1 <-data.frame('col_1'=rnorm(100),'col_2'=runif(100),'col_3'=rexp(100))
head(df1)
       col_1     col_2     col_3
1  1.1626853 0.7081688 0.1356186
2 -0.5859245 0.8679017 0.4680558
3  1.7854650 0.4107538 0.5867553
4 -1.3325937 0.3032165 0.4111656
5 -0.4465668 0.8882200 3.4235329
6  0.5696061 0.4715614 1.0981746
```

Now I want to filter my data :

```
df1 %>%
  filter(col_1>0)
```

However, I lost my unique numbering i.e. I have just new data frame with rows from 1-49 and I want to have old indexing with just data deleted. Is there any possibility how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Best approach would be to create a new column with row index as tibbles don't support rownames.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  filter(col_1 > 0)
```

Comment: I think `rownames_to_column()` from `tibble` is probably technically safer, because it preserves the "true" original row indexing, while taking the `row_number()` assumes sequential indexing, which is true here but may not always be.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep row index try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df1 <-data.frame('col_1'=rnorm(100),'col_2'=runif(100),'col_3'=rexp(100))
#Code
new <- df1 %>% rownames_to_column('id') %>%
  filter(col_1>0) %>%
  column_to_rownames('id')
```

Output:

```
         col_1       col_2      col_3
1   0.44582154 0.485113710 1.12780556
9   0.91338077 0.028025045 0.03392986
12  0.39850519 0.693677593 0.08575707
15  1.31992767 0.875082565 1.69923642
18  1.01032450 0.874306072 0.07470948
19  0.21004100 0.489900673 0.06544119
20  1.83231058 0.777010624 1.04503362
23  1.76636414 0.932134284 0.89963322
24  0.14665427 0.453811105 1.69614288
27  0.95768915 0.540466270 2.08754680
28  2.12894656 0.265205677 1.26068462
29  1.20613178 0.590121360 0.69933346
31  0.17498536 0.003435992 0.90773187
33  1.09692125 0.321649196 3.08840026
35  0.71434379 0.592343229 1.51961595
36  2.18998179 0.288959794 0.86319077
37  0.24424922 0.129267751 0.01765732
39  1.10932154 0.515400529 0.34381840
40  1.62120910 0.843270861 1.22549044
42  0.61201364 0.299831635 0.24302644
43  0.69583869 0.621354113 1.71074969
50  0.12516294 0.337942860 0.13970981
51  0.55032446 0.204976125 0.58245053
52  1.24819371 0.796629076 0.36528538
53  0.78363419 0.321154495 0.09472414
55  0.98528573 0.626797295 0.36268645
56  0.82932405 0.404080363 0.18517625
60  0.65893951 0.441280360 0.15770949
62  0.23747401 0.498418489 0.32947354
67  2.05117816 0.702286040 2.04353073
68  0.46038166 0.455878959 0.78142526
69  0.85814858 0.167027385 0.77806710
73  0.36265229 0.836850527 0.08689737
74  1.75032050 0.918432489 2.44187445
80  1.84781396 0.064257761 1.31418005
82  0.69448019 0.664345881 0.22248944
84  1.43213456 0.172975017 1.02372291
86  0.05623400 0.436021922 0.67705170
87  0.50485963 0.791348607 0.32379094
90  0.08281623 0.608697963 0.87405171
91  0.15252262 0.026808318 0.28446487
92  0.13104612 0.649343508 1.19998877
95  2.47542034 0.071355988 0.78619673
97  0.42994024 0.616706005 0.68963918
98  1.42811745 0.642106243 0.99258297
99  0.27834373 0.310252127 0.71026805
100 0.98552422 0.073099646 0.21789834
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   slice(which(col_1 > 0))
```